# If I install the Bitcoin progam on my computer, that simply means that I will be mining Bitcoins over time?

Tags: finance, ecommerce

I installed the [Bitcoin progam](http://www.weusecoins.com/en/getting-started) on my computer, does that simply means that I will be mining Bitcoins over time?

Otherwise what are the ways to mine Bitcoins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Bitcoin software allows you to receive, hold and send bitcoins. To mine you need specific hardware and software - for most people it is not recommended to bother.